# Need assistance with Paypal

Tags: paypal

Question about Paypal -- How do I include a "button" in an email that I am sending?  I created the button; however, the only option that is being provided is an option is for a website.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you please include more information?  What button did you create?  Is this in HTML?  What website option are you referring to?  How are you trying to send this email?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the URL for the image:

`<A href="http://www.somepage.com"><img src="apaypalbutton.img"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Paypal button, you should see (on top of the window where the code is generated) a "website" tab (which will give you the HTML code for your website) or "email" tab (which will give you the same code as a hypertext you can attach to a picture on your email).
However, if you create a button with drop down menus (option with prices...), the "email" tab won't be available which is probably your case here.
If so, I wouldn't be able to tell you exactly as it will depend from your e-mail provider but you might be able to include HTML code (so the "website" tab).
Otherwise, you can use the "send money" tab on the home page of your Paypal account to send invoices and payment request to your customers.